# How to solve the inequality $x^3 + 2x^2 - 2x - 1 < 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, cubics

What will be the solution to the following inequality?

$$x^3 + 2x^2 - 2x - 1 < 0$$

I can't solve this using the table of signs method. Please include an explanation as to how it was solved.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: your inequality is equivalent to $$(x-1)(x^2+3x+1)<0$$
solve $$x^2+3x+1=0$$ for $x$ and factor the equation
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{3}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: Will I need to use the quadratic formula?

Comment: Yes. Determine $a,b$ with $x^2+3x+1=(x-a)(x-b)$

Comment: But even if we know the zeros of $(x−1)(x^2+3x+1)$, what can we do if we are not allowed the "table of signs" method?  That is the method where we assume that the sign is unchanged in each of the intervals between zeros.

Comment: It is virtually impossible to avoid using a table of signs as the final answer *is* a table of signs.

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative of the LHS

$$3x^2+4x-2$$

has two real roots (as the discriminant is positive), so that the function has two local extrema and potentially three real roots. You can't escape from computing them, but you can also establish that the maximum is positive and the minimum negative, so that the three roots are there.

The LHS will be negative before the smallest root and between the two largest (which frame the minimum).

Answer (score 0):

We need to solve
$$x^3-1+2x(x-1)<0$$ or
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1+2x)<0$$ or
$$(x-1)(x^2+3x+1)<0$$ or
$$(x-1)\left(\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}\right)<0$$ or
$$(x-1)\left(x+\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)<0,$$
which by the intervals method gives the answer:
$$\left(-\infty,\frac{-3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{-3+\sqrt5}{2},1\right).$$
Done!